# ios animation won't start in 2nd view

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, ios7

Is there some line of code to add to stop your animation once you go into another view? When I switch views the code to run the animation is all there but it won't play, it is in -(ViewDidLoad). I'm not sure what I need to add.

Comment: You probably will need to show some of the code involved and describe the symptoms you're seeing for someone to be able to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about your implementation but if your animation code is in the `viewDidLoad` method you may need to move that code to the `viewDidApper` method. `viewDidLoad` is only (typically) called once during the lifetime of your view controller